# add icon on draggable jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add a "+" icon or a class attribute on draggable items. I'm using jquery Ui draggable method.

code :

```
    function deptStyleDroppable(){
    $('.deptName').parents("tr").draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        //revert: "invalid", // slide back, when dropping over non-target
        revert: function(dropped){
        // Return `true` to let the helper slide back.
            if(typeof dropped === "boolean"){
                // dropped == true, when dropped over a simple, valid droppable target.
                // false, when dropped outside a drop target.
                return !dropped;
            }
        // Drop comes from another tree. Default behavior is to assume
        // a valid drop, since we are over a drop-target.
        // Therefore we have to make an extra check, if the target node
        // was rejected by a Dynatree callback.
        var helper = $.ui.ddmanager && $.ui.ddmanager.current && $.ui.ddmanager.current.helper;
        var isRejected = helper && helper.hasClass("dynatree-drop-reject");
        return isRejected;          
        },
        connectToDynatree: true,
        cursorAt: { top: -5, left:-5 },
        helper: "clone"
    });
    }
```

How can i achieve this. Please help me out of this problem.

Thanking You.

Answer (score 0):

Draggable elements already have the `ui-draggable` css class once they are initialized.

But if you want to add your own one, just chain with `addClass(...)`. Same if you want to add an icon you can chain with `prepend()`:

```
$('.deptName')
    .parents('tr')
    .draggable({ ... })
    .addClass('your-css-class')
    .prepend('<img src="http://path-to-your-icon"/>');
```

I wrote this <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvH8m/)</kbd> to illustrate.